# Inquiry about NanoMQ Availability in Yocto Recipe

Tags: linux, ubuntu, yocto, yocto-recipe, yocto-layer

I hope this message finds you well. I am reaching out to inquire about the availability of NanoMQ in the Yocto recipe.

As part of our project requirements, we are interested in utilizing NanoMQ within our Yocto-based system. However, before proceeding, we want to confirm if NanoMQ is currently included in the Yocto recipe or if there are any known layers or recipes that provide support for NanoMQ integration.

If NanoMQ is available in the Yocto project, we would greatly appreciate any guidance on how to include it in our build and any potential considerations we should be aware of during the integration process.

If NanoMQ is not part of the existing Yocto recipe, we would be grateful for any information regarding community-contributed layers or repositories that provide support for NanoMQ or similar lightweight messaging protocols.

Thank you for your time and attention to this query. We are looking forward to your valuable insights and contributions to our project.

I tried R&D on this issue, but I haven't got any idea.

Comment: Seems to be a bog-standard cmake build. Recipetool should create at least a 99% working recipe out of the box: https://docs.yoctoproject.org/dev/dev-manual/new-recipe.html#creating-the-base-recipe-using-recipetool-create